# Mock infinite generator in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to mock an infinite generator function using the `mock` library. (Or `unittest.mock` if you have Python 3.3)

Here is a minimum working example of an infinite generator. If I can successfully mock this, then I will hopefully be able to mock the actual function I am using.

```
import itertools
def infinite_generator():
    thing = itertools.cycle([1, 2])
    while True:
        yield next(thing)
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import mock
import itertools
mock_func = mock.MagicMock()
mock_func.__iter__.return_value = itertools.cycle([1, 2])
```

I want `mock_func` to function exactly as `infinite_generator` functions.

e.g. I expect to be able to do the following:

```
>>> a = mock_func()
>>> next(a)
1
>>> next(a)
2
>>> next(a)
1
>>> next(a)
2
```

etc.

However, at the moment `next(a)` returns things like

`<MagicMock name='mock().__next__()' id='3043937712'>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave out `__iter__` here because you don't intend to iterate over the `mock_func` object itself:

```
mock_func.__iter__.return_value = itertools.cycle([1, 2])
```

Instead:

```
>>> mock_func = mock.Mock()
>>> mock_func.return_value = itertools.cycle([1, 2])
>>> a = mock_func()
>>> next(a)
1
>>> next(a)
2
>>> next(a)
1
>>> next(a)
2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after.